# code to get data from another workbook selecting sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy and paste data from multiple workbooks and multiple sheets. (name keeps changing of worksheets as well as workbook)

I have a code but here I need to manually select the cells. I just want to select the sheet and it should automatically import the entire data in the sheet to a designated worksheet in my workbook. Is that possible?

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:="Source Range", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure. You can first check for max row and check for max column then set range and copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "source" range to get its `Parent` sheet `UsedRange`, as follows:

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range

    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            With Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1)) ' open and reference current selected "source" workbook
                Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select any cell in the wanted sheet ", Title:="Source sheet chosing", Default:="A1", Type:=8) ' have user select any cell in source sheet
                If Not rngSourceRange Is Nothing Then ' if any valid "source" range selected
                    wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate ' this could be omitted since subsequent InputBox allowa user to switch between open workbooks
                    Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8) ' have user select "destination" cell
                    If Not rngDestination Is Nothing Then ' if any valid "destination" range selected
                        rngSourceRange.Parent.UsedRange.Copy rngDestination.Cells(1, 1) ' be sure to collapse "destination" range to a single cell
                        rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                    End If
                End If
                .Close False ' close referenced (i.e. current "source" sheet) sheet
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Working just fine for me. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of you can copy from one to the other. Let me know if you need help on something more specific.

```
Sub testing()

    Dim des_wb As Workbook, sou_wb As Workbook
    Dim des_ws As Worksheet
    Dim sou_rng As Range

    ChDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path)
    Set des_wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set sou_wb = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename)
    Set sou_ws = sou_wb.Worksheets(1)

    Set sou_rng = sou_ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    sou_rng.Copy
    des_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. Appreciate your effort. But I really need an option to choose from the available sheets of the workbook from where I want to get the data. (The data is not always in the same worksheet number).

Comment: @DebrupDutta I am aware of that. You can simple combine my code with yours. Just change the part that sets the source worksheet to your selection method.

Comment: Thank you so much.... really appreciate your effort. Thanks once again.